# "Non-static method Redis::get() cannot be called statically" in production but not in local

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-forge

While developing in the local environment I haven't any problems using `Redis` in my `master.blade.php`

```
<body class="{{Redis::get('app_theme')}}">
```

untill I deployed my project (Forge+DigitalOcean) and started getting:

> ErrorException: Non-static method Redis::get() cannot be called statically

My only thought was is might be deal with PHP itself, but versions are the same.
What else it might be??

UPD:
in my **config/app.php** specified that

```
'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```

Comment: Because the blade file is complied as a static resource. 

You need to put this code in your controller action, and just render it.

Comment: why then it working on my computer? what the difference?

Comment: @VirtualDevice sounds like you might be interacting with PHPRedis directly not the Redis facade from Laravel ... check the Redis doc page (under Database in the Laravel docs) for more information about the possible conflict

Comment: @lagbox thanks for the response. I checked in `config/app.php` and  `Redis` is configurated as Redis facade.....

Comment: @lagbox I also checked in `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` on the server -> there is no phpredis in dynamic extensions

Comment: how are you using redis? ... you have to have an extension or a library to do it

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using PHPRedis locally vs on your production.

As per Laravel documentation, if you are using the Redis facade along with PHPRedis, you should use a different name than "Redis" when specifying the alias in your app.php config file:

> If you plan to use PhpRedis extension along with the Redis Facade
> alias, you should rename it to something else, like RedisManager, to
> avoid a collision with the Redis class. You can do that in the aliases
> section of your app.php config file.

```
'RedisManager' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#phpredis